NG0203 and NullInjectorError on Angular17 Application with Keycloak
I'm having 2 issues on with my application in the Homolog server, the first issue is the NG0203 when i have an empty cache:

ERROR RuntimeError: NG0203: inject() must be called from an core.mjs:6531 injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with 'runInInjectionContext'.

and the second issue appears at random times after i have cached some stuff from leaving the webpage open and reloading a few times:

ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError (Standalone[_AppComponent])[_AutheticationService -> _AutheticationService -> _KeycloakService -> _KeycloakService]: NullInjectorError: No provider for _KeycloakService!

And this second error indicates that it's happening in:
authentication.service.ts:11:39  and 40:3
The first issue is "resolved" if the user keeps refreshing the page, which seems to create a cache or something.
The Second issue i have no idea why it's happening and i'm trying to debug my code to look for the cause.
I'll link the relevant code below:
Here's my authenticationService code:
import { KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';

import { inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

u/Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {
  private readonly _keycloakService = inject(KeycloakService);

  redirectToLoginPage(): Promise<void> {
    return this._keycloakService.login();
  }

  get userName(): string {
    return this._keycloakService.getUsername();
  }

  isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    return this._keycloakService.isLoggedIn();
  }

  async getToken(): Promise<string> {
    try {
      return await this._keycloakService.getToken();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error getting token', error);
      throw error;
    }
  }

  logout(): void {
    this._keycloakService.logout(environment.keycloak.postLogoutRedirectUri);
  }

  isSessionActive(): boolean {
    return !this._keycloakService.isTokenExpired();
  }
}

And here's my Keycloak Initialization:
import { KeycloakService } from 'keycloak-angular';

import { provideHttpClient, withFetch } from '@angular/common/http';
import { APP_INITIALIZER, ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideAnimationsAsync } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations/async';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { routes } from './app.routes';

export const initializeKeycloak = (keycloak: KeycloakService) => async () => {
  try {
    await keycloak.init({
      config: {
        url: environment.keycloak.authority,
        realm: environment.keycloak.realm,
        clientId: environment.keycloak.clientId,
      },
      loadUserProfileAtStartUp: true,
      initOptions: {
        checkLoginIframe: false,
        onLoad: 'check-sso',
        redirectUri: environment.keycloak.redirectUri,
        scope: 'openid',
      },
      enableBearerInterceptor: true
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Keycloak initialization failed:', error);
    throw error;
  }
};

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    KeycloakService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeKeycloak,
      multi: true,
      deps: [KeycloakService],
    },
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideAnimationsAsync(),
    provideHttpClient(withFetch()),
  ],
};

Main.ts
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import { provideHttpClient, withInterceptors } from '@angular/common/http';
import localePt from '@angular/common/locales/pt';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { provideRouter, withViewTransitions } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { appConfig } from './app/app.config';
import { routes } from './app/app.routes';
import { keycloakHttpInterceptor } from './app/interceptor/keycloak-http.interceptor';

registerLocaleData(localePt, 'pt-BR');

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    ...appConfig.providers,
    provideHttpClient(withInterceptors([keycloakHttpInterceptor])),
    provideRouter(routes, withViewTransitions())
  ]
}).catch(err => {
  console.error('Application bootstrapping failed:', err);
});

Any help understanding the issue is appreciated, Thanks in advance.
